# What is the proper value for Redis io-threads config in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I want to deploy Redis on Kubernetes. This Redis should handle a huge amount of commands and we are enabling `io-threads` config in our Redis.

Based on the request and limit resource values in Kubernetes, what should I have considered as `io-threads` config?

For example, I want to set 9 core CPU limit for this Redis instance and our Kubernetes cluster will guarantee 3 core request for it. What is the proper value for this config? I should set `io-threads` to 3 or I can set it to more than the request core like 5 or 6?

I have tried both 4 and 5, but there was no change in CPU usage and latency of executed commands and I just want to make sure higher values than CPU requests are fine for Redis.

Answer (score 1):

recommended read would be:

[Redis 6.0 new features: take you 100% to master the multi-threaded model](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000040376111/en)

and you should never fix the Cores for these services until you know you will be able to keep that much amount of cores at all time, else your deployments will fail where there is not enough room.